# Express: response get sent before asynchronous function finishes

Tags: javascript, express

---

```
app.get('/test',(req,res)=>{

     doSomething().then(res.sendFile(path,(err)=>{
        if (err) {
            console.log('err')
          } else {
            console.log('Sent:', fileName)
          }
      }))
```

async function doSomethig(){

let conf = {
url:'',
format:'jpeg',
out:'./out/test.jpg'
}

conf.url = "someurl";

```
return new Promise(async () => {
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,    
    //ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions']
  });
  console.log(`START => Contacting URL: ${conf.url}`)
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1024, height: 768 })
  await page.goto(conf.url)
  await page.waitForFunction('window.status === "ready"')
  console.log(`DONE => Contacting URL: ${conf.url}`)
  console.log(`START => Screenshot: ${conf.out}`)
  const data = await page.screenshot({
    path: conf.out,
    quality: 100,
    omitBackground: true,
    type: conf.format
  })
  console.log(`DONE => Screenshot: ${conf.out}`)
  //fs.writeFile(conf.out, data,  "binary",function(err) { });
  //console.log(data)
  await browser.close();
})
}

})
```

---

doSomething() create a file and save it in a local directory and i want to send it as a response to the get request but the get res.sendfile enters the err branch and prints error be cause the doSomething function don't finish to create the file.

Please help to fix the problem

Comment: Sounds like you're not awaiting something you should be awaiting in your `doSomething()` method, or you're resolving it too early. Can't tell though because you didn't include that method in your question.

Comment: check if `doSomething` returns a promise correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the `.then()` handler correctly: you need to pass a function to it that will be called once the promise has been resolved. Instead, you're executing `res.sendFile()` *immediately*.

The correct syntax:

```
doSomething().then(() => {
  res.sendFile(…);
});
```

Then in `doSomething`, you create a new promise for no reason, and with an incorrect syntax.

It should look like this:

```
async function doSomething() {
  let conf = { url:'', format:'jpeg', out:'./out/test.jpg' };
  conf.url = "someurl";

  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,    
    //ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions']
  });
  …
  await browser.close();
}
```